# $http-call-fails-while-deployed-in-windows-10-uwp

Tags: windows, ionic-framework, uwp

I have created an Ionic1 app for windows 10 UWP. Basically data stored locally from application using SQLite database and saved details will be moved to live server once the application connected to internet.

We use ASP.NET MVC WebAPI for handing live database related works. The problem here is AJAX call (XmlHttpRequest) failed to WebAPI while deploying the app into device and it is working fine while debugging in browser.

While running `ionic serve`, it is working perfectly in all browsers including *Edge*.

While running `ionic run windows --uap --archs=x86`, AJAX call fails. (I build the application using `ionic build windows --uap --archs=x86`)

Content Security Policy included in index.html:

```
< meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"' />
```

allow-navigation config.xml:

```
< allow-navigation href="http://*/*/" / >
```

Edit 1:

I found the cause in Visual Studio JavaScript console window as 'Network Error 0x2eff'.

Any idea about this?